# Unable to invoke aspect methods in an external jar/different project

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj, spring-aop, load-time-weaving

I have an external jar which contains an aspect which is to be used by my other projects but I am not able to call the aspect methods inside the external jar.
When I searched I came to know that I would have to use load-time weaving for my situation. So I added

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect"
        weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver"/>
```

in my application context xml file and also added an aop.xml file in the META-INF of the external jar/project which contains the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC  "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
   <weaver>
    <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
    <include within="com.mstack.genie.audit.aop.*"/>
   </weaver>

   <aspects>
    <!-- weave in just this aspect -->        
    <aspect name="com.mstack.genie.audit.aop.AuditAspect"/>
   </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

I  also added `spring-instrument.jar` in my main project. Even after all this I am not able to call the aspect methods from the external jar. I saw other links too with same question but still my issue was not solved. I am using gradle as my build tool. Can anyone please help me out in this?

Comment: Did you start your Java VM with a java agent (`-javaagent ...`)?

Comment: Should I use a java agent? Doubtful about that because it's a spring Web application that I run on eclipse. So this java agent part was always kind of tricky  for me. Would I need to use java agent? I am asking out of ignorance

Comment: Well, actually the best thing would be to use compile-time weaving, but if that's not applicable, the load-time weaving via a java agent way would be much cleaner than fighting against classloaders using reflection, like Spring would try to do in this case.

Comment: The problem is when my services are REST services and all this is a part of it. Is there no cleaner spring way of getting this done? I did try the load-time-weaver in the application context but still doesn't work.

Comment: Well, it's your choice after all, I'd go with compile time weaving, but load time weaving with a proper java agent would work as well. If you choose to go with classloader magic, it's still doable, but I won't be willing to help you debugging that.

Comment: Ok ...so I can get this done by compile time weaving too. Thank you. I would try the compile time weaving like you said. Thanks again

Comment: BTW: `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` applies to Spring AOP (proxy-based) while `<context:load-time-weaver .../>` applies to full AspectJ LTW. You do not want to use both at the same time because you might get your aspects applied twice if they are picked up by both Spring and AspectJ.